# can't fully understand how the RAM modules speed works (related to the hardware limitations)

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, overclocking

I'm building my first desktop computer and I've discovered lots of things. Some of them regarding the RAM modules speed:

I've seen that Intel specified in their official stats that [the i7-14700K can support up to 5600 MT/s when using DDR5 RAM modules](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/236783/intel-core-i7-processor-14700k-33m-cache-up-to-5-60-ghz/specifications.html#:%7E:text=Up%20to%20DDR5%205600%20MT/s), but the motherboard I need, the ROG Strix Z690-G Gaming WiFi by ASUS, can support even a higher speed, [it supports up to 6000 MT/s when overclocking](https://rog.asus.com/motherboards/rog-strix/rog-strix-z690-g-gaming-wifi-model/spec/#:%7E:text=DIMM%2C%20Max.%20128GB%2C-,DDR5%206000(OC),-/5800(OC)/5600).

So my question is... How the RAM modules speed works effectively? I can't understand why there's a possibility of going even higher if the CPU has a limitation at 5600 MT/s. Could them ever reach those 6000 MT/s with everything working properly?

Maybe there's something related to overclocking that I don't know (I'm just a beginner).

Hope someone could help me understanding more.

Answer (score 2):

Almost all modern processors will state their *guaranteed* "if you get this speed it will work" that assumes that the motherboard manufacturer has done the bare minimum needed to support that processor.

The silicon lottery also plays into that. Some processors might have perfect silicon that is be able to run the memory controller at 7200MT/s, some might only be able to run at 6000MT/s. Intel only guarantee that every processor will run at 5600MT/s. The memory controller in theory can operate at a wide range of speeds.

One of the problems with modern memory is that it has a very wide interface, meaning that it has a lot of address and data lines that need to all be very closely matched. If one or more lines is slightly longer or shorter than others then those differences will need to be detected and compensated for. This is something that is worked out in "training" the memory. The interface is calibrated to figure out the specific delays needed for each line to achieve the correct speed.

On top of that the motherboard quality plays a big part.

Typically the specifications for the DDR5 memory and/or will say "the data lines must all have the same length +/- 0.508mm", "all the (slower) address lines lengths must be within 1.27mm of each other" "data lines cannot be this close due to cross-talk" and a lot of other things that precisely limit how the lines are allowed to interact with each other.

A motherboard manufacturer can go above and beyond in order to make sure the wires on their board are well matched, have good clearance to other lines, well grounded, and are generally more precisely matched than the specifications ask for. A faster clocked memory speed needs much better matched line lengths, clearances and layout.

The result is that the data lines could have less noise than the specification and the processor ratings are expecting, and you could have gotten some "good" silicon that can run at better speeds.

Because of that the processor might be able to run the data lines faster before the timing or noise makes it difficult to be able to reliably transmit data. The processor may well be able to run their memory at speeds well beyond their rating, but they only say the speed that absolutely every processor is guaranteed to support.

The CPU lists what it expects to be able to support given the limits they told the manufacturers. It doesn't stop the manufacturer from making their board better than what they were told, and you getting silicon that can run at top speed without issues.